# Handling timezone with .Net and Oracle

Tags: .net

My application use .Net as front-end and Oracle as backend.

We have Location master table where we will keep associated time zone. We need this time zone because application demands date time conversion form one location to another.

This time zone conversion functionality  is required at both end .Net(C#) and Oracle(PL/SQL package)

Problem starts here, .Net understand Microsoft Timezone version where as Oracle understand TZ version

1. Which time zone I should associate with location,
2. If I associate TZ time zone , then I can leverage inbuilt oracle functions for time zone conversion but .Net  will not understand this.
3. If I associate MS time zone , then I can leverage .Net API for time zone conversion but Oracle will not understand this
4. Should I Associate either TZ or MS and then use a time zone mapper to map between TZ to MS

I don’t  think I am the first person who come across this scenario , I would like to know how others approach the workaround and what is the best practices

Comment: Jon Skeet has written awesome blog @ http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/nodatime/

Comment: It saw that but it dosn't talk about how to deal with MS time zone and TZ at the same time